# Python OrderedDict with lambda

Tags: python, ordereddictionary, defaultdict, python-collections

Can we have an ordered dictionary, with some default value?

As in case of `defaultdict`, i can define something like:

`a = collections.defaultdict(lambda:[True,True])`

Can we have the above `lambda` functionality, but have elements inserted in the dict such that the order is maintained?

Comment: we have ordered dict, why you don't use that?

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question looks good, but be sure to read the comments on that answer.